# How to convert special characters in filePath to upload in node without 500 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8, decode, encode

Trying to fix a bug when uploading assets with special characters via an adobe extension built with `node`, however the characters are encoded when trying to upload.

**Example**

*Original asset name:*

`Venice нещо си на друг език искам да видя.jpeg`

*The special characters are encode to the following:*

`Venice%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%20%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%8F.jpeg`

I've tried using: `decodeURI(filePath)` and `decodeURIComponent(filePath)`, both work at decoding the url however, on upload I get a `500 internal server error`. Not sure what's causing the 500 error.

I have also tried `filePath = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( filePath ) )`, as well as the package `npm i utf8`, but no luck with either.

Can anyone suggest anything else I could try?

Comment: In the first place you should check why the server responds Error 500.

Comment: @Andrew I should have mentioned that I have tried this, but the logs don't show anything in relation to my issue unfortunately. There is an implemented debugger which shows the error starts as a 500, then reattempts the upload but gets a `400 error 'Duplicate first chunk'`, it tries a third & final time and ends at a 400 error again.